# P2P chat client for android

Tags: android, sockets, networking, nat, instant-messaging

I am planing to make a P2P chat application for android:

So here's my idea:

1. The client will connect to a server to download a list of IP addresses (of friends)
2. Then it will try to open a socket to a friends ip address (on a specified port) and write it to the socket
3. The friend's client will open a socket and read it from there.

The idea is simple (perhaps too simple?) but there seems to be an inherent problem with the idea.

With NAT and Dynamic IP finding the actual IP can be difficult.

Even if the client periodically updates it's IP address on the server (we can get it's local IP from the device itself and we can get the public IP from server), When I need to open a socket to a device what ip address do I open the socket to? The public or local IP?

Obviously the opening a socket to the local ip cannot work, but if I open a socket to the public IP (and my friend's client is listening at the other end), how is the message supposed to reach my freind's device?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use private addresses since they are not routed on public internet, so you need to use public IP. Finding the real IP address is maybe not so difficult since the request to your server will come from that public IP. The real challenge is how to mitigate problems that PAT (NAT) creates. You can try with IGD protocol (UPnP) to do automatically configure port mapping but not every router supports it. Also you can use UPnP to get the public IP as well.